# Covariance and Contravariance in Interfaces

Tags: c#, covariance, contravariance

Here is an example of using covariance and contravariance for generics

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ICovariant<Apple> alCov = new Covariant<Apple>();
            ICovariant<Fruite> fCov = alCov;

            IContravariant<Apple> aContra = new Contravariant<Apple>();
            IContravariant<Apple> fContra = new Contravariant<Fruite>();

        }


        public class Fruite
        {
            public virtual void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fruite");
            }
        }

        public class Apple : Fruite
        {
            public override void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Apple");
            }
        }

        interface IContravariant<in T>
        {
            void Method();

            // This interface can be implicitly cast to MORE DERIVED (downcasting)
            // Usually means T is used as argument
            void Method(T argument);
        }//interface

        interface ICovariant<out T>
        {
            // This interface can be implicitly cast to LESS DERIVED (upcasting)
            // Used for readonly collections
            IEnumerable<T> GetList { get; }
            // Used when T is used as return type
            T Method();
        }//interface


        public class Covariant<T> : ICovariant<T>
        {
            public IEnumerable<T> GetList
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public T Method()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        public class Contravariant<T> : IContravariant<T>
        {
            public void Method()
            {
                Console.Write(typeof(T));
            }

            public void Method(T argument)
            {
                Console.Write(argument);
            }
        }

    }
```

I understand these lines of code  because it is similar to polymorphism  and I understande the benefit behind it

```
ICovariant<Apple> alCov = new Covariant<Apple>();
ICovariant<Fruite> fCov = alCov;
```

but what I do not understand is the benefit of the contravariance like in the following lines

```
IContravariant<Apple> aContra = new Contravariant<Apple>();
IContravariant<Apple> fContra = new Contravariant<Fruite>();
```

so could anyone explain with example of how can I take the benefit of it.

Comment: `IEqualityComparer<Fruite> c = new FruiteComparer(); var d = new HashSet<Apple>(c);`

Answer (score 1):

*`so could anyone explain with example of how can I take the benefit of it.`*

One example of use could be the following:

```
 IContravariant<Fruite> fContra = new Contravariant<Fruite>();
 List<IContravariant<Apple>>  contravariants=  new List<IContravariant<Apple>>();
 contravariants.Add(fContra);
 contravariants.Add(aContra);
```

so if you change your `IContavariant<in T>` interface 
to `IContavariant<T>` you will get a compile time error

one good example could be the `Distinct` method in `Linq` you can think of a method that does the same thing but does not use `IEqualityComparer<T>` but the same algorithme to all  fruits

in this link you can find a full example
[Comparing Generic Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654061.aspx)